# Multiline Text in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, text

In Flex I want to create a Text file and it is working, but the problem is  all inputs are written in one line;

here the cods

```
        addText.text="[ \r\n"
        addText.text=addText.text+"] \r\n";
        fileRef.save(addText.text, "data.txt");
```

the current result is like below;

```
[]
```

how can I make it like this;

```
[
]
```

Answer (score 0):

i would start trying

> addTextxt.text = "[ \n ]";

it normally works in all cases...

good luck ( :